# Move insufficiently answered question to stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, migration, questions, site-policy

More than 3 weeks ago I posted [a question on Code Review asking help with naming a module I created](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/need-help-with-naming-marshaling-interface-calls). I did not receive any answers, so I was wondering whether it would be okay to move it to stackoverflow in order to receive responses.

So, move it? Yes or No?

(Please answer yes, please answer yes!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FAQ says that *"Code Review - Stack Exchange is for **sharing code** from projects you are working on for peer review"*. I've just flagged it with the the following message:

> There is no code, maybe it would be better on StackOverflow, Programmers.SE or Theoretical Computer Science.

So, yes :-)

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case, as palacsint pointed out, the question was off-topic and should have been asked on programmers in the first place. It has now been migrated to programmers and will hopefully get answers there.

However in general questions that are on-topic here, will almost always be off-topic on SO or programmers and re-asking them there will only get them closed. So in general that's not recommended.

Comment: The funny thing is that it got an "off topic" close vote almost immediately... Just the one, not seeing it getting closed, and imho it fits perfectly in Programmers, but still funny...